# Почему не работает проверка на InternetConnection?

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать чтоб приложение проверяло наличие Wifi и Internet соединение.
Но аппликация вылетает, но пойму почему

**Вот код : с классом проверки**

```
package com.example.tanya_.learnhebrew;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class CheckInternetConnection {

private Context context;

public CheckInternetConnection(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
}
```

**А вот с функцией теста : **

```
public void test(View view) {
    CheckInternetConnection connection = new CheckInternetConnection(this);

    boolean check = connection.haveNetworkConnection();

    if (check){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**и вот такая ошибка : **

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

**и вот такая ошибка : **
    com.example.tanya_.learnhebrew.CheckInternetConnection.haveNetworkConnection

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Проблема не в классе проверки, а где то при обработке нажатия на кнопку, приложите кусок когда из разметки, где устанавливается обработчик для кнопки.

Comment: Ну так функция `public void test(View view)` - это и есть функция обработчика кода. Или я не так понял вопрос?

Comment: Все разобрался. В моем случае не был добавлен пермишн. Я ниже сделал ответ на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле проблема в том, что не добавлен пермишн в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```